# R Vignette Fails on Internal Package Function

Tags: r, devtools, r-package, roxygen2, vignette

We are adding a vignette to our R package. When documenting the package using `roxygen2`, the vignette breaks giving the error

```
Error in tMatrix[i, j, ] <- testVec : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

However, using `devtools::document()` or `devtools::build_vignettes()`, the vignette builds fine.

Minimal example located [here](https://github.com/GilChrist19/vignetteExample).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because R sets `LC_COLLATE` to `C` when building packages, which is often *not* the collating sequence of the locale of common operating systems such as those you mentioned in the Github issue [yihui/knitr#1719](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1719). Because [you used `sort()`](https://github.com/GilChrist19/vignetteExample/blob/8973dbc7f2589ca2e281fa343547a98f742bedb4/vignetteExample/R/array.R#L27) in the `makeArray()` function in your minimal example, and `sort()` depends on `LC_COLLATE`, you will get different results in your R console (where `LC_COLLATE` is often not `C`) and in `R CMD build`. To reproduce the error:

```r
# Copied from https://github.com/GilChrist19/vignetteExample/blob/8973dbc/vignetteExample/R/array.R#L8-L45
makeArray <- function(names = c("AA", "Aa", "aa")){


  size <- length(names)
  tMatrix <- array(data=0, dim=c(size, size, size), dimnames=list(names, names, names))
  testVec <- setNames(object = numeric(size), nm = names)

  # fill up the array
  for (i in names)
  {
    for (j in names)
    {

      j_name <- strsplit(j, split='')[[1]]
      i_name <- strsplit(i, split='')[[1]]
      ij_prod <- as.vector( outer(j_name, i_name, paste0, sep='') )

      # sort
      ij_prod <- vapply( strsplit(ij_prod, split=''),
                           function(x) {paste0(sort(x, decreasing=TRUE), collapse='')},
                           FUN.VALUE = character(1))

      for (k in ij_prod)
      {
        testVec[k] <- testVec[k]+5
      }

      # testVec[] <- testVec/sum(testVec)

      tMatrix[i,j, ] <- testVec

      testVec[] <- 0
    }
  }


  return(tMatrix)
}


Sys.setlocale('LC_COLLATE', 'C')
makeArray()
```

I'll leave it to you to decide what to do with `sort()` since I'm not familiar with your function. One hint I could give is that `sort(method = 'radix')` always follows the `C` locale, hence is more robust to different locales.